# CSS positioning using "+" to activate is not working

Tags: css

I go to change the position of a div in css using `+` (example: `p.foo:hover + div.foo {}`) but it does not seem to work properly.

```css
.foo { 
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: top 1s ease-out, right 1s ease-out;
          transition: top 1s ease-out, right 1s ease-out;
}

#footext:valid {
  outline: solid blue 2px;
}
#footext:invalid {
  outline: solid red 2px;
}
#footext:valid + .foo {
  top: 50px;
  right: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
    <input id="footext" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="q" value="" placeholder="Search" required />
</div>
```

[Edit the code here](http://jsfiddle.net/Lno8hLbq/)

**EDIT:** Fixed the code in both the link and here

Comment: Where is the rest of your code? I cant find anything with the class search

Comment: Let's ask the right questions first. ***Do you understand what `+` means in CSS?***

Comment: Is .search the button? If so, because you got the input box jammed with a top right of 0,0 the search button will wrap to be below the input box.

Comment: Sorry for missing code, I just forgot to remove the class in the input and change the `.search` to `.foo`.  Yes I know what `+` means, I used to use it a lot and it isn't working for some reason.

Comment: the `#footext:valid + .foo` in its current form will never work ,because `#footext` is a child of `.foo` not a sibling to `.foo` ,instead if u mean u want to give both the same style then use `,`

Comment: @ctf0 well is there any option to have a child tag affect the parent tag? if not I will just have to recode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no CSS selector for selecting a parent of a selected child.

This could be done with JavaScript

The + CSS selector will select any element that is the next child element of the same parent.

B + E   : Any E element that is the next sibling of a B element

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors

See also:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 0):

Please, declare class "search". you can repair html like this

```
<div class="foo">
  <input id="footext" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="q" class="query search" value=""     placeholder="Search" required />
</div>
```

and then try using this css for CSS positioning

```
#footext.search:valid {
  top: 50px;
  right:50%;
  position:absolute;    
}
```

Comment: #footext.search:valid {
  top: 20px;
  right:20px;
  position:absolute;    
}